# Sql update statement with named parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public void UpdateRegistration(User userModel)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = BaseRepository.OpenConnection())
        {
            string query = "UPDATE [dbo].[TBUser] " +
                "(CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate) VALUES " +
                "(@CreatedBy, @CreatedDate, @ModifiedBy, @ModifiedDate) WHERE " +
                "UserId = @UserId;";
            connection.Execute(query, userModel);
        }
    }
```

I get the following exception while it runs

```
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Incorrect syntax near '('.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException</ExceptionType>
```

userModel has all of the properties associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [field] = Value
WHERE ....
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

So your query should be

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TBUser] 
SET CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
    CreatedDate = @CreatedDate,
    ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy,
    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate
WHERE UserId = @UserId;
```